# How to register a List<string> in JS and iterate it?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

I wrote some code in ASP.net:
Code behind:

```
public string Locations { get; set; }
public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
public List<string> Hrefs { get; set; }
public string CategoriesJ { get; set; }
public string HrefsJ { get; set; }

...
    this.CategoriesJ = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Categories);
    this.HrefsJ = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Categories);
```

JS in markup:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
       var Categories = jQuery.parseJSON(this.CategoriesJ);
        var Hrefs = jQuery.parseJSON(this.HrefsJ);
function onInit(){
    alert(Categories[0]);
};
</script>
```

Is that OK to use index is such Json var?
Is this the right way to write?

So why don't I see the alert?
The code behind var equals: ["restaurant","restaurant"]
I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference server-side variables in the ASPX like that. In ASP.NET you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var Categories = <%= CategoriesJ %>;
   var Hrefs = <%= HrefsJ %>;
function onInit(){
    alert(Categories[0]);
};
</script>
```

Comment: What is the difference between <%= and <% and <%# ?

Comment: `<%` is a code block which executes on the server-side during page render, `<%=` is the same but returns an expression to the block to be written out during page render, `<%#` is an expression that binds to a control property during databinding. There's some inline expressions documentation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) that explains the types of code block better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct. To loop through all values, use:

```
for(var x=0;x<Categories.length;x++) {
     alert(Categories[x]);
}
```

Comment: I parse a list to Json in the code behind and then parse it again to Json in the markup ? Isn't there a shorter way ?

Comment: It's basically a nested JavaScript array. How to get to the elements depends on the structure of your JSON. If you can post a sample by editing your question I'll try to help.

Comment: I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null